# Why do I get blank %3 character when trying to encode reserved characters of a URI Component in javascript?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, escaping

Here is the situation presented as-is in the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/am4ph9ut

```
function encodeAllCharacters(){
    var result = "%60~!%40%23%24%25%26*()_%2B-%3D%7B%7D%7C%5B%5D%3B%3A'%22%2F.%2C%3C%3E%3F%60";
    result = result.replace(/[!'()*-_.~]/g, function(c) {
        return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    });
    return result;
}
```

This is a simplified version of the `fixedEncodeURIComponent` method explained in this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

I am not sure why I get `%3` added after every character after the `regexp` is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression uses `-` inside the character class (ie. the square brackets) which means all the characters between the one on the left to the one on the right of the `-` (inclusive),  eg.  `[c-f]` will match c,d,e,f.

To match against the character `-` itself use the backslash to escape it:

```
result = result.replace(/[!'()*\-_.~]/g, function(c) {
```

Comment: Woops, how silly of me to overlook it! Thanks a ton!